# Checking for letters in a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, algorithm

I'm making algorithm which checks if letters from second word exist in the first word. So for example: ["hello", "hey"] should return false and ["hello", "Ello"] should return true.
Here is my code:

```
function mutation(arr) {
  var array = arr[0].toLowerCase();
  var word_temp = arr[1].toLowerCase();
  var word = word_temp.split("");
  var l = word_temp.length;
  var number = 0;
  for (i = 0; i == l; i++) {
    if (array.indexOf(word[i]) > -1) {
      number++;
    }
  }
  if (number == l) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

mutation(["zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba", "qrstu"]);
```

I don't know why but it isn't adding anything to variable `number`. I don't want a solution of full algorithm. I would only like to know why variable `number` is still equal to zero.
Thank you all for your time :)

Comment: `var array = arr[0].toLowerCase();` This is not an array. Using suitable variable names is a necessity for good code.

Comment: Also, you don't need an else.  Close the if and return false straight after.

Comment: Ohh, you are right. I missed this one, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`For` loop:

> If the value of condition is true, the loop statements execute. If the value of condition is false, the for loop terminates.

Your statement is `false` from the beginning. Just change `i == l` to `i < l`.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is wrong. It should be:

```
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
//Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is unnecessary complicated. You could just go like so.

```
function mutation(arr) {
    return (arr[0].toLowerCase().indexOf(arr[1].toLowerCase())>=0);
}
console.log(mutation(["zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba", "qrstu"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function mutation(arr) {
  var first = arr[0].toLowerCase();
  var second = arr[1].toLowerCase();
  return first.indexOf(second) !== -1;
}

console.log(mutation(["zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba", "jihg"]));
console.log(mutation(["hello", "ell"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
I fixed my for loop and made code shorter. Then I also tried solution with include which was even easier.
Thank you all so much!